# Is it possible to reduce an algebraic function to $1$s and $0$s?

Tags: limits, exponentiation, infinity, binary-operations

I want to know where in this process I'm going wrong. Perhaps it's not even a valid thing to do...?

Take a well-behaved function such as $f(x)=x \sin 2x$.

[image]

I want to turn this into a new function $g$ that, in the limit, becomes a series of $1$s and $0$s.

**Step 1: Remove negative domain**

$f \rightarrow f^2$

[image]

**Step 2: Reduce function to range $[0,1]$**

$f^2 \rightarrow \frac{2f^2}{f^4+1}$

[image]

**Step 3: Push function towards $0$ or $1$**

Raise to the power of a variable $k \geqslant1$.

$\frac{2f^2}{f^4+1} \rightarrow \biggl(\frac{2f^2}{f^4+1}\biggr)^k$

Here are the results of $k=2$ (blue), $5$ (orange) and $10$ (green):

[image]

You can see where this is going :-)

**Step 4: Take limit**

I suspect that this is where it all goes wrong:

$g(x)=\lim \limits_{k \to \infty}\biggl(\frac{2f^2}{f^4+1}\biggr)^k=\lim \limits_{k \to \infty}\frac{2f^{2k}}{(f^4+1)^k}$

It seems logical to me that, in the limit as described, $g(x)$ outputs nothing but $0$s and $1$s. Therefore, multiplying $g$ with some other function - for example, $g(x)h(x)$ - should produce $0$ for $g(x)=0$, and $h(x)$ for $g(x)=1$.

But for large $k$, $g=O\bigl(\frac{1}{k^2}\bigr)$. So even though no single operation removes $1$ from the domain, the final function is always equal to $0$. Effectively, everything 'collapses' to $0$ at the limit. Do I have this right?

I assume that this has to do with a zero-dimensional 'spike' not being a real mathematical entity; it's a form of singularity.

But, as I said, I'd appreciate knowing exactly what's wrong. And, of course, if it's possible to fix.

Perhaps the only solution is to define a function specifying the $1$s and $0$s, and take it from there?

Comment: It would help ourselves, but mostly yourself if you try to formalize what you mean by *Is it possible to reduce an algebraic function to 1s and 0s*. Here you're providing a sequence of operations, but not explaining your final intent.

Comment: Try $g(x) =
\begin{cases}
1,  f(x)>0.5 \\
0, f(x) \le 0.5
\end{cases}$

Comment: Thanks to both of you. My final intent was to use simple *algebraic* expressions to create a function that has $g(x)=1$ as its output for some values of $x$, and $0$ for all other values. @Vasya has suggested a version of what I asked in my last sentence: "Perhaps the only solution is to define a function specifying the $1$s and $0$s, and take it from there?". And it's very possible that this is the only answer. I was asking if there was an *algebraic* way of doing this - but given that my A-level in Maths is a long-distant memory, perhaps I simply don't have the vocabulary...

Comment: $g\ne O\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)$.

Comment: OK, so $g = O(\frac{2}{k^2})$, no? We ignore the $+1$, leaving $\frac{2f^{2k}}{f^{4k}}$. Is this correct? But we have reduced $f$ to $0s$ and $1$s, so my question was (and is), does the big-O order of $g(x)$ reduce all instances of $g(x)=1$ to $g(x)=0$ at $\lim \limits_{k \to \infty}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your $g(x)$ will be $1$ at all points where $x\sin(x) = \pm 1$ and zero everywhere else.  That is $$g(x)=\begin {cases} 1&x\sin(2x)=\pm 1\\0& \text{otherwise} \end {cases}$$
This is because $\lim_{k \to \infty}1^k=1$ but the limit of any number smaller than $1$ when raised to a high power is $0$.  This is a fine discontinuous function.  The uniform limit of continuous functions is continuous, but this limit is not uniform so the limit function can be discontinuous.

Comment: OK, thank you. That's exactly what I was aiming for, and exactly how I arrived at it (harnessing the unique multiplicative and exponential properties of $1$). Would you mind explaining the term "fine discontinuous function", though? I get that it's discontinuous, but what does "fine" mean in this context?

Comment: And can I just confirm that the big-O issue is a red herring? Then I'll mark this as answered.

Comment: That is right.  It is not true that $g=O(\frac 1{k^2})$ because at the points where it is $1$ it doesn't decrease.  It doesn't matter how fast the other points decrease as long as they go to $0$.

Comment: As I thought, but wasn't sure. Reassuring! Many thanks @Ross Millikan :-)